# How to re-arrange my data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, associations, apriori

Thank you for your interest.
I want to rearrange my data frame to perform association rules easily.
I will use apriori.

I looked many solutions using pivot and transpose. But I failed it.

**There are UNIQUE [116807 'id' and 170 'visit_nm', and 11 'country']**

These are my datasets as shown below.

[image: 1]

I expect the output for apriori.

[image: 2]

So, ultimately I want market basket results like

[image: 3]

Thank you, have a good coding day.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['visitnm'])`

OR for "duplicate visit", to add visit for each id, do:

`pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['visitnm']).groupby('id').sum()`